# How do I move a partition in on macOS?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, diskutil

I'm migrating data from a 525GB drive to a 1TB drive. Part of the reason I'm doing this is the APFS container got messed up on the 525GB drive (I have backups).

The first thing did was `dd` the data from the 525GB drive to the 1TB drive (partition table and all). Of course, the partition table was wrong (and `diskutil verifyDisk` reported this) since it was too small for the 1TB drive. I fixed that with `diskutil repairDisk`.

Then I deleted the APFS container (since it was messed up and I plan to copy the data from a Time Machine backup). The space where the APFS container was is the `Untitled` partition.

So now the partition table looks like this:

```
/dev/disk2 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                           SIZE        IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                               *960.2 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                            209.7 MB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                       314.0 GB    disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS UEFI Boot Manager              1.0 GB      disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                       209.6 GB    disk2s4
```

As you can see, the sizes of the partitions don't add up to the size of the disk. I'd like to resize disk2s2 to fill the remaining space on my 1TB drive. However, `diskutil resizeVolume` won't expand that partition any further because it's already up against disk2s3 and disk2s4. I'd like to move my disk2s3 and disk2s4 partitions to the end of the drive (right now they're at the end of the first 525GB of the drive.

How do I move partitions in macOS?

Comment: If you used `dd` to move partitions between drives, then why not use `dd` to move a partition on the same drive? Is your question how add the new partition to the GPT?

Comment: I didn't move the partitions individually with `dd`, I moved all the drive data (partition table + partitions) in one fell swoop. I could delete the two partitions at the end and then re-create them, but I'm concerned that I may loose something the Bootcamp Assistant put in the GPT or MBR.

Comment: When you move Windows, you can encounter a situation where Windows will not boot. In such cases, you will need to reinstall the boot files. This is not difficult to do, but this is a separate question. The Boot Camp Assistant creates the partitions for the installation of Windows, but nothing special is added that differs from installing on a PC.

Comment: I don't really want to just provide an answer recommending a single product, but [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) ought to be able to handle this. [I can't remember if they do a working free trial.]